# What does MOV RAX,qword ptr FS:[0x28] mean?

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm trying to understand what `MOV RAX,qword ptr FS:[0x28]` means. I get that `FS:[0x28]` is a stack canary. If my understanding is correct the data from `RAX` gets copied by `MOV`. Then there's a comma which separates the first operand `MOV RAX` from the second one `qword ptr FS:[0x28]`. What exactly does does `qword ptr FS:[0x28]` do?

Comment: This question is already answered here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10325713/why-does-this-memory-address-fs0x28-fs0x28-have-a-random-value

Comment: Yeah, I already looked at that post, but it wasn't very clear to me.

Comment: This is intel syntax, so the value gets copied __to__ `RAX`, not _from_. `qword ptr FS:[0x28]` just means it references a quadword at memory location 0x28 in the FS segment.

Answer (score 3):

It is not clear from the context of the question but it depends on the platform, if you are on Windows then fs:[0x28] is the field ArbitraryUserPointer according to the following data structure.

```
ntdll!_NT_TIB
   +0x000 ExceptionList    : Ptr64 _EXCEPTION_REGISTRATION_RECORD
   +0x008 StackBase        : Ptr64 Void
   +0x010 StackLimit       : Ptr64 Void
   +0x018 SubSystemTib     : Ptr64 Void
   +0x020 FiberData        : Ptr64 Void
   +0x020 Version          : Uint4B
   +0x028 ArbitraryUserPointer : Ptr64 Void
   +0x030 Self             : Ptr64 _NT_TIB
```

You can find some information about this field in the TEB here:

- https://codemachine.com/articles/arbitraryuserpointer_usage.html
- https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20190418-00/?p=102428

Answer (score 0):

The assembly you posted is in Intel syntax.

`MOV RAX, qword ptr FS:[0x28]`

The sentinel value stored is being copied into `RAX`, not from it. This code is part of a setup for copying the value into a stack canary.